# Linq RemoveAll removes all items

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection newLinks of datarows with several records. Here is the table structure

```
LinkSysId | LinkId | Col1 | Col2
1           1        str    str1
2           1        str5   str4 
3           2        str2   str3
4           2        str6   str7
```

I want to make a linq query, which would iterate the collection and leave only top 1 distinct LinkId record:

```
LinkSysId | LinkId | Col1 | Col2
1           1        str    str 
3           2        str3   str3
```

I tried to make like this

```
newLinks.RemoveAll(rowComp => newLinks.Any(rowDel => 
                   rowComp["linkId"].ToString() == rowDel["linkId"].ToString() 
                   &&  rowComp["linkSysId"].ToString() != rowDel["linkSysId"].ToString()));
```

But it removes all items from the collection? Thanks for any help

Comment: Funny, the title sounds like all's well.

Comment: @GertArnold I was really surprised, because it makes the delete after iterating the whole list. I think the reason of such logic is to avoid Halloween Problem in iteration.

Comment: Note that `RemoveAll` is not a part of LINQ at all.  It's a method of `List`, not `Enumerable`.

Comment: @Servy But why it removes items only after iterating the whole list?

Comment: @voo Because otherwise you'd get concurrent modification exceptions.  Try executing something like `foreach(var item in list) list.Remove(item);` and you'll see why they need to do all of the removing at once, at the end.

Comment: @Servy yes, now I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "create new" approach:

```
DataTable keepTheseRows = table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("LinkId"))
    .Select(g => g.First())  // takes the first of each group arbitrarily
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 3):

There are LINQ extension libraries that implement DistinctBy(), which is what you are looking for. However this small snippet utilizes the fact that Add() method on hashset returns false if identical item is already added:

```
var foundIds = new HashSet<int>();
var FirstLinkId = newLinks.Where(row=>foundIds.Add(row.LinkId)).ToList();
```

Comment: This is of course how `Distinct` is generally implemented, with just a tiny bit of extra logic for having a separate selector, a key comparer, argument validation, etc.  This is the heart of the LINQ `Dictinct` or most custom `DistinctBy` implementations though.

Answer (score 1):

As Tormod says, the best approach is to use a `DistinctBy()` implementation.

(In particular, look at Tormod's implementation and you'll see it's effectively the same as the DistinctByImpl() method below, so this answer should be taken to be an expansion of his.)

If you use DistinctBy(), the solution becomes as simple as:

`var uniques = list.DistinctBy(item => item.LinkId);`

A good implementation of `DistinctBy()` can be found in [Jon Skeet's `MoreLinq` library](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) which is also [available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.DistinctBy/).

As an example, here's an implementation using a copy of the DistinctBy() implementation from MoreLinq. Do not use this code though - use NuGet to download the original commented code.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Test> list = new List<Test>
            {
                new Test(1, 1),
                new Test(2, 1),
                new Test(3, 2),
                new Test(4, 2)
            };

            var uniques = list.DistinctBy(item => item.LinkId);

            foreach (var item in uniques)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public Test(int linkSysId, int linkId)
        {
            LinkSysId = linkSysId;
            LinkId = linkId;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("LinkSysId = {0}, LinkId = {1}", LinkSysId, LinkId);
        }

        public int LinkSysId;
        public int LinkId;
    }

    static class EnumerableExt
    {
        public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
            (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
        {
            return source.DistinctBy(keySelector, null);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
            Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
        {
            if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
            if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("keySelector");
            return DistinctByImpl(source, keySelector, comparer);
        }

        private static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctByImpl<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource> source,
            Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
        {
            var knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
            return source.Where(element => knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)));
        }
    }
}
```